# how to map the columns from the restapi response to the database table columns?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am pulling the data from restapi in azure data factory and loading the data to sql server. after connecting the the restapi url the response of the data is given below . I need to map the columns to the table in the sql server. How can i map the columns from restapi response to table columns.

"@odata.context": "https://io-dev.crm3.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/$metadata#Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.indskr_iOFetchAuditDataResponse",
    "JSONOutput": "{\"AuditDataSet\":[{\"AuditID\":\"f45eb7ab-0b57-e911-80f4-0004ff9d7444\",\"ChangedBy\":\"f8ac67d9-e7c0-e811-a979-000d3af49c6c\",\"ChangedColumns\":null,\"ChangedDate\":\"2019-04-04T18:58:50Z\",\"ChangedNewValues\":null,\"ChangedOldValues\":null,\"Event\":33,\"SourceEntityName\":\"indskr_positiongroups\",\"SourceRecordID\":\"b5ba61b6-e651-e911-a97f-000d3af49c44\",\"SourceRecordName\":\"Position Group

Comment: What data would you like to store? What's the source schema? What have you tried? Please provide us with some more context.

Comment: the response which i am getting from the Restapi needs to be loaded to the table. which i have mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: You did show the json, but what table structure do they need to be mapped to? In short: deserialize the json into a (dynamic) object and read stuff from there. Also: see [Azure Data Factory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-factory/)

Comment: column name in the table :
AuditId,ChangedBy i have given just first two columns.

Comment: I am new to azure data factory . could you please help in in resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial about [Azure Data Factory – Copy Data from REST API to Azure SQL Database](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/azure-data-factory-copy-from-rest-api-sql-database-rohit-vangala).

You should create a table on destination Azure SQL database firstly.

This tutorial can help you copy the data from restapi in azure data factory and loading the data to sql server step by step.

Such as mapping the columns to the table in the sql server:

**Table mapping**:
[image]

**Schema Mapping**:
[image]

Hope this help.

Comment: In my scenario am pulling the by post request  The response which i am getting is  given below.

Comment: In my scenario am pulling the by post 
request  The response which i am getting is  reading as single string I need to split the data mentioned in the early comment .I need to map the columns AuditID, ChangedBy columns and there values to the destination table.

Comment: Yes, I know. And did you try this tutorial? Copy data from rest api to Azure SQL, it‘s actually means copy the data  responsed by rest api and then insert the data to the destination table in  SQL database. If you get some error messages, you can show us. Others and I all can help you.

Comment: I have shared the screen shot . Please check and let me know how to resolve this.